# How to test method which returns another method using EasyMock?

Tags: java, easymock

I am writing test case using EasyMock. My test method calls "returns verification.getVerification(paramter 1, paramter 2, parameter 3)". When I invoke my test method from test class, it returns null.

Sharing my code snippet below:

```
//EntityField.java

private Class <? extends Entity> classtype;
private String paths;
Permission filter;
@Inject
private transient RestrictInterface restriction;

public EntityField(final Class <? extends Entity> classtype, final String 
path, final Permission filterclass)
{
   this.classtype = classtype;
   this.paths = path;
   filter = filterclass;
}

public Permission getBasePermission() //my test method
{
   if(Active.class.isAssignableFrom(classtype))
   {
      filterclass=new 
    SimplePermission(Active.active_attribute,Operator.equals,Boolean.TRUE);
}
else if (NotActive.class.isAssignableFrom(classtype))
{
    filterclass=new 
    SimplePermission("notactive",Operator.equals,Boolean.TRUE);
}
return restriction.getBasePermission(classtype,filterclass);
}


//Test.java
@Test
public void testgetBaseRestriction() {
//NiceMock


EntityField entityfieldobject = new EntityField (classtype, path, 
filterclass);

//Mock Objects
RestrictInterface restriction = createNiceMock(RestrictInterface.class);
Permission filter = new 
SimplePermission(Active.active_attribute,Operator.equals,Boolean.TRUE);
final Class = Active.class;

//expects 
expect(restriction.getBaseRestriction(eq(classtype),eq(filterclass)))
.andStubReturn(filter);

//replay
replay(restriction);

Permission object = entityfieldobject.getBasePermission();
 // here object returns null    

verify(restriction);
}
```

I wanted to test whether filterclass value is set or not in my test class.
How to avoid this null value in test case. Any help would be appreciated.

**Thanks**

Comment: methods don't return methods. they return the result returned by that other method call

Comment: post complete `EntityField.java` code

Comment: seems like you want to actually mock the `verification` object.

Comment: @MoritzPetersen indeed

Comment: I have mocked verification object in my test class.

Comment: Then also getting null value in my test class. I am stuck since days.

Comment: We need to see at least the `EntityField.getVerification()` code and the code that you omitted where you set the comment "Written expects and replay statements". But it would be best to see the whole code.

Comment: @Stultuske methods may return lambdas which may be seen as "returning a method", though that's not the case here of course.

Comment: Added working code to test.

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer, now that I have full code:
`restriction` doesn't seem injected in `entityfieldobject`, So the null is normal. EasyMock is not aware of `@Inject`. Please do inject the dependency yourself. I recommend to use constructor injection for that.

The code below gives a good example.

```
import static org.easymock.EasyMock.expect;
import static org.easymock.EasyMock.mock;
import static org.easymock.EasyMock.replay;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;

public class TestClass {

    @Test
    public void testgetBaseRestriction() {
        Verification verification = mock(Verification.class);
        expect(verification.getVerification("1", "2", "3")).andReturn(new Permission());
        replay(verification);

        EntityField entityfieldobject = new EntityField(verification);
        assertNotNull(entityfieldobject.getVerification());
    }

}

class Permission {}

interface Verification {
    Permission getVerification(String s1, String s2, String s3);
}

class EntityField {

    private final Verification verification;

    public EntityField(Verification verification) {
        this.verification = verification;
    }

    public Permission getVerification() {
        return verification.getVerification("1", "2", "3");
    }
}
```

Comment: The mock, `expect` and `replay` aren't mentioned. So it's not fully working code.

Comment: Please share your thoughts.